# Bring div to font a div and back a div using CSS

Tags: css, html

As I mentioned in title. I have 3 divs and I want div2 in front of div1 but behind div3. I'm using CSS / CSS3. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by making use of a CSS ptoperty called z-index.

You would need to define your classes for div1, div2 and div3 as follows:

```
#div1 {
    background-color: Orange;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#div2 {
    background-color: Red;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#div3 {
    background-color: Yellow;
    z-index:2;
}
```

You can take a look at a sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/h7fx8/1/

EDIT:

If there's no div2 and only a shadow of div3 then it could work this way: http://jsfiddle.net/h7fx8/2/

Comment: Thanks @Satwik. Now if there's no div2 but shadow of div3 then how it works?

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your comment. Let me know if I have understood your question correctly and that, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's not exactly I mean but thanks to your example I solve my problem. Thanks again. @Satwik

Answer (score 0):

z-index is your best bet but is not supported by some older versions of browsers, namely ie. you can achieve the same result if you have

```
 <div>
 </div>

 <div>
 </div>

 <div>
 </div>
```

If you have divs that can be inside of one another, another option would be

```
 <div>
    Content
         <div>
             Content
                 <div>
                      Content
                 </div>
          </div>
 </div>
```